# Uncaught TypeError: jQuery(...).popover is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is the code that has error.

```
jQuery(window).on("load",function(){(cssua.ua.mobile||cssua.ua.tablet_pc)&&jQuery(".fusion-popover, .fusion-tooltip").each(function(){jQuery(this).attr("data-trigger","click"),jQuery(this).data("trigger","click")}),jQuery('[data-toggle~="popover"]').popover({container:"body",content:function(){return jQuery.parseHTML("<div>"+jQuery(this).attr("data-html-content")+"</div>")},html:!0})}),jQuery(window).on("fusion-element-render-fusion_text fusion-element-render-fusion_popover",function(t,e){jQuery('div[data-cid="'+e+'"]').find('[data-toggle~="popover"]').popover({container:"body",content:function(){return jQuery.parseHTML("<div>"+jQuery(this).attr("data-html-content")+"</div>")},html:!0})});
```

Answer (score 0):

You call `jquery` functions by first selecting an object using `$()` notation and then accessing methods and functions from there. You can learn more at [this JQuery Introduction](https://learn.jquery.com/about-jquery/how-jquery-works/).

```js
$( document ).ready(function() {...
```

I strongly recommend reading the [documentation](https://api.jquery.com/).